# Regex remove before colon notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

So I want to remove all text before the colon ":" so example

```
d016eb66c977d646642d491ae8461134:12345asdf
90ef258293ee214d1128abecd7b96f99:61231afad
```

To be

```
12345asdf
61231afad
```

**edit:** I've already tried this `^[^:]*:` but i ended up with only one line

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: This ^[^:]*: but it removed the lines so i ended with only 1 line

Comment: Please edit your question with that you have tried :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `^[^:]*:`, use `^.+:` because `[^:]` matches also newline.

Find what: `^.+:`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

**Don't check** `dot matches newline`

**Edit** according to comment:

This will match the last occurrence of `:` within each line.

If you want to match the first occurrence of `:` use `^.+?:`

Comment: This `^.+:` expression  matches from the beginning of a line till the *last* occurrence of `:`. Use `^.*?:` or `^[^:\n]:` to remove up to the *first* `:`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You're right, but it is not said in question which `:` must be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following with `multiline mode` enabled:

```
^[^:]+:
```

This must be replaced with an **empty string**, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bQ3yJ0/1).

Answer (score -1):

Use `[^ ]*:` (don't forget to add the space between `^` and `]`)

Comment: Didnt work at all it selected the whole txt document