# How do i remove everything behind :

Tags: notepad++

I have a problem.
In notepad++ When I to clear everything behind : in replacement, I did ^[^:]+:
But the problem is that the format of lines is name1:name2:name3
And I would like to remove the name1: so I would just have name2:name3
Any ideas?

Comment: If you match `^[^:]+:` and replace with an empty string, the result is `name2:name3` See https://regex101.com/r/cysPNl/1

Comment: I have more than 1 line of it when i do that it and click replace all it will also remove name2:

Comment: Try excluding the newline as well `^[^:\r\n]+:`

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: Can you add a full example to the question and what the result should be?

Comment: my lines look like
name1:name2:name3
So i want to remove the name1:

Comment: You could check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217137/regex-remove-before-colon-notepad or https://superuser.com/questions/1420401/notepad-delete-until-colon-for-every-line-with-replace-all

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's a bug :( in Npp, use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^:\r\n]+:(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  [^:\r\n]+     # 1 or more not colon or linebreak
  :             # a colon
  (.+)          # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I experienced the same behavior (bug) on Notepad++ v7.5.8 and your solution works for me ++